# Fork and Join (Graph)

Tags: graph, multiprocessing, fork-join

How would we describe the following graph like the example (with fork and join)?

[image: graph]

In the example below why does the "count" start with 3?

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would we describe the following graph like the example (with fork and join)?

```
    P1;
    FORK L1;
    FORK L2;
    P2;
    FORK L4;
L3: JOIN 2;
    P5;
    Goto L4;
    
L1: P3;
    FORK L3;
L2: JOIN 2;
    P4;
    P6;
L4: JOIN 3;
    P7;
```

Up to 5 tasks may concurrently execute

> why does the "count" start with 3?

It just is a name for the constant 3 that is later used for a JOIN. It denotes the number of threads that need to arrive at that `JOIN Count` statement before the joined thread will continue with further tasks. That 3 corresponds to the number of incoming arrows at node `S7` in the graph.